# error : The literal 1111111111111000 of type int is out of range

Tags: java, junit, binary, literals, twos-complement

This is the method that I am testing

```
public static char[] convertDecimalTo2sComp(int decimal) {
    char [] bits = new char [16];
    double temp;
    int tempInt;
    String bitStr = " ";


    for(int i = bits.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        //negative input
        if(decimal <1) {
            temp = Math.pow(2,16); //add 2^number of bits, then convert to binary
            decimal += (int)temp;
        }
        //non-negative input
        tempInt = decimal%2;
        bitStr = tempInt + bitStr;
        decimal/=2;

    }
    bits = bitStr.toCharArray();

    return bits;
}
```

And this is what I'm getting the error: The literal 1111111111111000 of type int is out of range, in JUnit from

```
    @Test
public void testNegativeDecimal() { 
    int data = -8; 
    assertEquals(1111111111111000, Convert.convertDecimalTo2sComp(data)); }
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the number you've given is outside of the range of an int (which has a max value of 2^31-1 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Since you've declared it as a literal java assumes that you number is an int.

The easiest way to declare that the number should be a Long instead (which has a max value of 2^63-1)
`assertEquals(1111111111111000L, Convert.convertDecimalTo2sComp(data));`

Of course, you could also choose to make it explicit for the sake of readability

```
long expected = 1111111111111000;
assertEquals(expected, Convert.convertDecimalTo2sComp(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

For the given long value ie: 1111111111111000, You just have to add character 'l' in the end of the value. For Example:-

long value = 1111111111111000l;

Answer (score 0):

1111111111111000 as int is indeed outside the int range. 10^16 = ca. 2^48
Indeed you intended to have a char array:

```
public void testNegativeDecimal() { 
    int data = -8; 
    char[] expected = "1111111111111000".toCharArray();
    assertEquals(expected, Convert.convertDecimalTo2sComp(data));
}
```

or a more lazy, less error prone solution:

```
public void testNegativeDecimal() { 
    int data = -8; 
    String expected = "0000000000000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(data);
    expected = expect.substring(expected.length() - 16);
    assertEquals(expected, new String(Convert.convertDecimalTo2sComp(data)));
}
```

The latter having the advantage that on error you see the (human readable) Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by addressing your underlying confusion.

Judging from your method-name `convertDecimalTo2sComp` and your parameter-name `decimal`, you're expecting the argument to be "decimal" (base-10) in some sense. But in fact, that's not true: the argument is just an integer in the range [−2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>31</sup>−1], *not* specifically a base-10 representation of that integer. Internally, in fact, it's actually represented as a two's-complement binary integer — for example, if the integer is −8, then it's represented internally as `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000` — but that only matters when using bit-level operations such as `&` (bitwise "and") and `>>` (right-shift). It may *seem* like integers are represented in base 10, because conversions to and from strings use base 10 by default (e.g., `Integer.toString(32)` is equivalent to `Integer.toString(32, 10)` and `Integer.valueOf("32")` is equivalent to `Integer.valueOf("32", 10)`), and because we usually write them in decimal form in the source code (e.g., we usually write the integer 32 as `32` rather than `0x20` or `040` or `0b10_0000`); but that's all just for our convenience, and has nothing to do with the internal representation.

So, for example, these statements are all *exactly* equivalent:

```
System.out.println(32);
System.out.println(0x20);
System.out.println(040);
System.out.println(0b100000);
System.out.println(0b_0010_0000);
```

because in all cases, the integer 32 is represented internally as `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000`.

---

With that cleared up . . .

To assert that something is a character array containing thirteen `'1'`-s followed by three `'0'`-s, you can either use `Assert.assertArrayEquals` [[link](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertArrayEquals(char[],%20char[]))], or you can convert the `char[]` to a `String` and use `Assert.assertEquals`. So, any of these:

```
assertArrayEquals(
    new char[] {
        '1', '1', '1', '1',  '1', '1', '1', '1',
        '1', '1', '1', '1',  '1', '0', '0', '0'  },
    Convert.convertDecimalTo2sComp(data);

assertArrayEquals(
    "1111111111111000".toCharArray(),
    Convert.convertDecimalTo2sComp(data));

assertEquals(
    "1111111111111000",
    new String(Convert.convertDecimalTo2sComp(data)));
```